# Dependency Injection And Fluent Design

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns, builder

Say you have a spring component like below with dependencies constructor injected *(builder is a singleton)*:

```
@Component
public class houseBuilder{

     private WindowMaker windowMaker;
     private DoorMaker doorMaker;
     private RoofMaker roofMaker;

     @Autowired
     public houseBuilder(WindowsMaker wm, DoorMaker dm, RoofMaker rm){
            this.windowMaker = wm;
            this.doorMaker = dm;
            this.roofMaker = rm;
     }

     //Other methods omitted for brevity

}
```

However the house requires something called "foundation" that should be passed in through the constructor or set before making the house begins  and foundation is not a spring bean. I'd like to use the builder pattern as well so I could do something like the below but I am unsure how to do this with spring. Something like the below is what I am after except I want to use spring:

```
Foundation foundation = new Foundation();

HouseBuilder hb = new HouseBuilder(foundation)
.windowMaker(args)
.doorMaker(args)
.roofMaker(args);
```

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: @CoffeelsProgramming : The *Builder* and *Factory* patterns solve two different design problems. What is your reasoning behind mixing the two?

Comment: Could you suggest a solution with either Builder or Factory for the current problem?

Comment: Explain your use case in more actual detail first. The standard response is usually "make the foundation a bean".

Comment: Say you had the below where 12 is the # of pizzas passed in by the user. i.e. not suitable for a bean.

Pizza pizza = new Pizza.Builder(12)
                       .cheese(true)
                       .pepperoni(true)
                       .bacon(true)
                       .build();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring Dependency injection and fluent builders are not really designed to work together.

The first is a way to set dependencies of an object in an "automatic" way via annotation or configuration.
While  the second is a way for clients of the class to specify how the object should be build.

Automatic dependency injection and declarative construction are so really two distinct ways to create objects.

As a side note, Spring dependency injection with constructor brings two major fluent builder benefits : no more cumbersome constructor to call as the injection is performed by the container and the object may be immutable as no setter are required.